# Normalizing rows of pandas DF when there's string columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to normalize a Pandas DF by row and there's a column which has string values which is causing me a lot of trouble. Anyone have a neat way to make this work?

For example:

```
               system  Fluency  Terminology  No-error  Accuracy  Locale convention  Other
19  hyp.metricsystem2      111           28       219        98                  0    133
18  hyp.metricsystem1       97           22       242        84                  0    137
22  hyp.metricsystem5      107           11       246        85                  0    127
17   hyp.eTranslation       49           30       262        80                  0    143
20  hyp.metricsystem3       86           23       263        89                  0    118
21  hyp.metricsystem4       74           17       274        70                  0    111
```

I am trying to normalize each row from `Fluency`, `Terminology`, etc. Other over the total. In other words, divide each integer column entry over the total of each row (`Fluency[0]/total_row[0]`,  `Terminology[0]/total_row[0]`, ...)

I tried using this command, but it's giving me an error because I have a column of strings

```
bad_models.div(bad_models.sum(axis=1), axis = 0)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: What would be `total_row[0]`? The sum of all integer columns for row 0?

Comment: Yes, exactly. it's basically normalizing over rows

Comment: What about `Locale convention`? Should it include `Locale convention`?

Comment: Great question @richardec.

Answer (score 0):

Use `select_dtypes` to select numeric only columns:

```
subset = bad_models.select_dtypes('number')

bad_models[subset.columns] = subset.div(subset.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
print(bad_models)

# Output
               system   Fluency Terminology  No-error  Accuracy  Locale convention     Other
19  hyp.metricsystem2  0.211832     0.21374  0.145418  0.193676                  0  0.172952
18  hyp.metricsystem1  0.185115    0.167939  0.160691  0.166008                  0  0.178153
22  hyp.metricsystem5  0.204198    0.083969  0.163347  0.167984                  0   0.16515
17   hyp.eTranslation  0.093511    0.229008  0.173971  0.158103                  0  0.185956
20  hyp.metricsystem3  0.164122    0.175573  0.174635  0.175889                  0  0.153446
21  hyp.metricsystem4  0.141221    0.129771  0.181939   0.13834                  0  0.144343
```

Comment: @skidjoe. Did you have time to test my answer?